# Meteor: MongoError: not authorized for query on db.collection when using authentication

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I followed [meteor/mongodb: Use different DB for authentication & read/write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979274/meteor-mongodb-use-different-db-for-authentication-read-write) to a T and am receiving the error when trying to query the db:

```
Exception while invoking method 'myMethod' MongoError: not authorized for query on myDB.bobRocks
```

I setup the user in Mongo using:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
    {
    user: 'bob',
    pwd: '12345',
    roles: [
        { role: 'readWrite', db: 'myDB'},
    ]
    }
)
```

My Database call is:

```
var myDB = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://10.10.10.100:27017/myDB");
BobRocks = new Mongo.Collection('bobRocks', { _driver: myDB })
```

Finally I'm using:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://bob:12345@10.10.10.100:27017/admin meteor run
```

What am I missing? I would assume the authentication would follow the MONGO_URL declaration but it doesn't appear to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux then you have to export the mongourl like then meteor run like this.

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://bob:12345@10.10.10.100:27017/admin meteor run
```

Or if you are using windows then you have to set the mongourl then meteor run.

```
SET MONGO_URL=mongodb://bob:12345@10.10.10.100:27017/admin meteor run
```

Please try to connect using mongo cli first.

You also didn't pass username and password here

```
var myDB = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://10.10.10.100:27017/myDB");
```

You can pass username and password here like you pass in mongo url like this.

```
var myDB = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://bob:12345@10.10.10.100:27017/myDB");
```

And please make sure myDB is exist on remote server.

Comment: in the script for the actual node app I am using the export as you mentioned. If I also have to pass username and password in the Meteor app, wouldn't that negate some security?

Comment: Also, when I use the mongocli and authenticate to "bob" using `use admin    db.auth('bob', '12345')` I can fully manipulate the myDB (insert, query, etc.)